# how to use 'Linux-based' libraries with 'Windows-based' libraries in the same python script?

Tags: python, windows-10, ubuntu-20.04

Firstly, I have an objective of using using tesseract-OCR to extract data with. However, I have a pdf file which needs to be converted into JPEG, which is said to be easily carried out by the pdf2image library.

That sounds simple enough, but I get confused with how certain libraries are 'apparently' either one of the following: 'dependencies', are 'wrappers' or simply Windows or Linux based.

Particularly, a 'feature', that is 'convert_from_path' that I feel I will needs as I have directories to attend my pdfs from, requires a [library called 'poppler' that - 'is in Linux](https://github.com/Belval/pdf2image)' The readme text suggest manipulating a .path file which was not obvious to me as it was in a r'' string? I know regex  starts with r'' strings, but how that is important to adding paths it was not specified.

Moving on, I followed a recent thread [installing WSL](https://towardsdatascience.com/poppler-on-windows-179af0e50150) which I had done. Now I have a linux terminal in Pycharm IDE where I have recently installed PIP3. From here, it was advice I install the packages I require. But on which terminal? Install using BASH? or the default terminal (however you call it for windows?).

This also brings me to the title of my question. Say I install it in BASH, does that mean I can import the library like so:

```
import matplotlib                #pre-installed with CMD venv
import os                        #pre-installed with CMD venv
import pillow                    #pip-installed with CMD venv
import tesseract-ocr             #pip-installed with CMD venv
import poppler                   #pip3-installed with BASH  # and how does a CMD venv even interact with a BASH? 
import pdf2image                 #pip-installed with CMD venv, but is a wrapper that is on linux?
```

will these libraries simply be read by both the python for windows and python for Linux serially? (as in, if it cant 'read' the library in window, it would go to the next interpreter that is the Linux interpreter if I have added it in in my venv interpreter's settings?)

Also, Pycharm runs on a python 3.7, while WSL Linux has a default python 3.8.10. Not to mention WSL -version does not exist for windows when I thought I could just update them so they match.

At this point, the answer I am hoping to receive, is whether an import method like above - installed by different 'systems' inside a python ide such  as Pycharm or even when ran in CMD would work or would not work and why not?

Comment: I see now that you're using WSL, which I didn't catch on my first read-through. That's a whole extra layer of abstraction and complication to worry about while you're figuring this stuff out for the first time. I agree with KJ, stick to one OS at a time unless and until you have a compelling reason not to.

Comment: @CrazyChucky I have a python interpreter active in my IDE. But I could also add the interpreter that comes with linux WSL installation 3.8.10. I am running and only intend to run venv.

Comment: However, could you guys clarify how problematic as @KJ had mentioned? i.e., in an event that I need a library from either OS apps, does simply adding a Linux and Win python in venv works?

Comment: regarding the fact that poppler is available in windows. How come it is adviced to manually uncover these files on github and not simply do a pip-install procedure? I fear the time when I need to migrate, things would become even less beginner-friendly when they add more version. Have you guys got any sources to understanding how github: clone, source code works? I'd love to read them. Or  even better, a source for this specific problem I am confused about?

Comment: I mix Python on Linux/Windows frequently. Most libraries will run fine on both platforms. The biggest exception I can think of is pywin32, which is specifically designed for only Windows. If there are slight differences, you should be able to overcome with OS detection and then do different things in `if` statement. Regarding PyCharm, if I recall correctly, they really steer you towards virtual enviroments. Which can be OK if you know what the score is or a real mess if you think you have certain modules installed, but they're really in a different Venv.